# what's the data's meaning collected by cadvisor?

Tags: docker, influxdb, cadvisor

I use cadvisor+influxdb to monitor the performance of docker container, the data collected by cadvisor was stored in influxdb, but I don't know the meaning of the data,can anyone explain the meaning of data or tell me how cadvisor calculate the cpu usage? The data below shows the data stored in influxdb. Thanks in advance.

### cpu_usage_per_cpu

`time              container_name      instance      machine           value 
2017-06-25T...         "/"               "1"       "40e90a2a7e09"   4882667197496`

The column value is number and I don't know the number's meaning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Docker Container CPU Usage as Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271942/get-docker-container-cpu-usage-as-percentage)

Comment: @ha100 Thanks for your reply. The main problem is that I don't know the column value's meaning. What dose the number "4882667197496" mean?