# Convert Long to Float and Integer

Tags: java

I have an object that has some cpu stats. The problem is that those that's are in type `long` (i think)

How can I convert this to usefull values like `float` and `int`?

I tried to cast it but I got

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

[image]

```
float value = (float) Docker.getStatistics("ENVX").getCpuStats().get("system_cpu_usage");
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert a `long` (or a `Long`) to a `float`? You'd lose precision.

Comment: longs are certainly "usefull values". In fact more useful then float in most cases

Comment: Out of interest, what is not useful about a `long`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Docker Container CPU Usage as Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271942/get-docker-container-cpu-usage-as-percentage)

Comment: I mean I just wanted to show the actual data. This is an API and the values are in long. I want to show percentages of the cpu

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand why would you want to convert a 64-bit value to a 32-bit, risking to lose precision, but you can try with:

```
Long cpu = Docker.getStatistics("ENVX").getCpuStats().get("system_cpu_usage");
Float f = Float.valueOf(cpu.toString());
```

Comment: I mean. I think this should be the cpu percentage. I can't really use a long value. I need something like 0-100%. **Maybe I should convert to double?**

Comment: Then you don't need any `float`s, nor `double`s, but simple maths. :)

Comment: Maybe I am an idiot then. I thought this was supposed to give the raw values already.