# How can I get CPU usage percent with docker.containers.stats?

Tags: python-3.x, docker

Code:

```
import docker
cli = docker.from_env()
print(cli.containers.get('container1').stats(stream=False)['precpu_stats'])
```

Output:

```
{'cpu_usage': {'total_usage': 6121320874, 'percpu_usage': [4662552384, 1458768490], 'usage_in_kernelmode': 970000000, 'usage_in_usermode': 4940000000}, 'system_cpu_usage': 24545140000000, 'online_cpus': 2, 'throttling_data': {'periods': 0, 'throttled_periods': 0, 'throttled_time': 0}}
```

How Can I get CPU usage percent from these informations?
I used `docker stats` command on terminal and I got 0.11% CPU usage.
But I can't get that 0.11% from this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Docker Container CPU Usage as Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271942/get-docker-container-cpu-usage-as-percentage)

Comment: I calculated the values but I got wrong percentage.
So that didn't help.

Comment: I read it again and I realized that I made a mistake and it helped me a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update from February of 2023, with mem stats:

```
stats = self._container.stats(decode=False, stream=False)

mem_bytes_used = stats["memory_stats"]["usage"]
mem_bytes_avail = stats["memory_stats"]["limit"]
mem_gb_used = round(mem_bytes_used / (1024*1024*1024), 1) 
mem_gb_avail = round(mem_bytes_avail / (1024*1024*1024), 1) 

cpu_usage = (stats['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage']
             - stats['precpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage'])
cpu_system = (stats['cpu_stats']['system_cpu_usage']                    
              - stats['precpu_stats']['system_cpu_usage'])
num_cpus = stats['cpu_stats']["online_cpus"]
cpu_perc = round((cpu_usage / cpu_system) * num_cpus * 100)
cpu_max_perc = num_cpus * 100
```

I've noticed sometimes some fields in the dict are missing/empty, so you might want to put a "try/except KeyError" around it.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I got The answer and it's way is a little long...

```
import docker
cli = docker.from_env()
print(cli.containers.get('container').stats(stream=False)['cpu_stats'])
print('---------------------------------------------')
print(cli.containers.get('container').stats(stream=False)['precpu_stats'])
```

Output is:

```
{
'cpu_usage': 
    {
     'total_usage': 25382985593,
     'percpu_usage': [17829217240, 7553768353],
     'usage_in_kernelmode': 3280000000,
     'usage_in_usermode': 21040000000
    },
'system_cpu_usage': 75406420000000,
'online_cpus': 2,
'throttling_data': 
    {
     'periods': 0,
     'throttled_periods': 0,
     'throttled_time': 0
    }
}
---------------------------------------------
{
'cpu_usage': 
    {
     'total_usage': 25382168431,
     'percpu_usage': [17828400078, 7553768353],
     'usage_in_kernelmode': 3280000000,
     'usage_in_usermode': 21040000000
    },
'system_cpu_usage': 75400410000000,
'online_cpus': 2,
'throttling_data': 
    {
        'periods': 0,
        'throttled_periods': 0,
        'throttled_time': 0
    }
}
```

And now for getting percentage we have to do these:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
stats = client.containers.get('container').stats(stream=False)
UsageDelta = stats['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage'] - stats['precpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['total_usage']
# from informations : UsageDelta = 25382985593 - 25382168431

SystemDelta = stats['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['system_cpu_usage'] - stats['precpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['system_cpu_usage']
# from informations : SystemDelta = 75406420000000 - 75400410000000

len_cpu = len(stats['cpu_stats']['cpu_usage']['percpu_usage'])
# from my informations : len_cpu = 2


percentage = (UsageDelta / SystemDelta) * len_cpu * 100
# this is a little big because the result is : 0.02719341098169717

percent = round(percentage, 2)
# now The output is 0.02 and thats the answer.
```

Comment: As of the 15/12/2021 (docker-py 5.0.3),  you get system_cpu_usage by doing stats["cpu_stats"]["system_cpu_usage"] and  stats["precpu_stats"]["system_cpu_usage"]

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/mdaum/a80913e9c828d4bad3714a709f49586e
This typescript implementation will poll the container stats endpoint of your local docker dameon, and compute the utilization each time. You will see that the computations are lining up one-for-one with reported utilization from your dashboard.

[image: Run Example]